# what is mounting windows 7 file system

Tags: windows

Something is mounting my windows 7 disk on `/media/jim/0236A16836A15E03`
and I can't find out what is doing it.

I installed a thing named `nautilus` which I found referenced in another questions answer.
I can't find 'nautilus either'.

I want to mount my windows disk from `.bashrc` on something easier to remember but how do I know what device it is on?

Answer (score 0):

Your partition with windows7 is mounted by `automount`.

This is usual. Because your partition seems to have no `label` it is mounted under a mountpoint with his `UUID` name.

Now you have two ways to fix this

1. set the label of the partition

you can set the partition name using `gparted`, which happens to bee a GUI partition manager.

You can install it using `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Then you locate your windows7 disk and right-click on it, the you select the option `label` and enter your favourite name like *windowsData*.

2. using `fstab`

If you just want it to a specific place like `~/windows` you may use the file `/etc/fstab`

insert a line like this:

```
UUID=<your UUID>      /home/<you>/mountpoint  auto user,rw,nodev 0  0
```

using `sudo nano /etc/fstab` or `sudo vim /etc/fstab` or `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

The the partition will be mounted automatically at every boot.

*by the way*:

The 'thing' `nautilus` is a filemanager. He is not really the part for mounting partitions.

Comment: Thanks.  I used fstab with the "LABEL=" option.  The man page for fstab does not have an entry for type=auto nor for the options rw and nodev.  Do you know where I can find that information?

Comment: Err, currently I do not know from where this comes. I am just using it since I am using fstab. Maybe these options should get documentated in the man system. I know that this is working, because I just copied it out of my fstab.