# Permamounting an HDD or partition

Tags: automount

happy new year tp all of you, hope that this new year brings you all joy and happiness and succes, money, women, all that your hearts desire.

Im here on a quest, to seek help:

I have Linux on a dual-boot with windows 7. I have some files (large files to be precise) on the windows partition. Everytime i need to acces them i have to wait a couple of minutes so that Ubuntu mounts the partition, and many times i have to mount using terminal.. he just cant seem to do it on his own sometimes (weird though...)

so the question is, how to make it auto mount a partition (or a HDD for that matter) on startup?

I have checked some answers on this forum before seeking help. If i understood correctly i have to create a mounting point usinfg /mkdir then change something using fstab? But id really like an explanation on how, and why, and what each command does? I mean, to copy paste, i can do that, but id like to undestand what im really doing

the name of this partition (using df in terminal): /dev/sda3.

So thanks all for reading this message, and thank you for those who are going to answer.
Saucy

Comment: After you added HDD to fstab you can try adding "mount *hdd name*" to /etc/local.rc it should work

Comment: @XperianX `/etc/rc2.d` might be more usefull, so always if his gui is started it is mounted. if you are using `/etc/fstab` you do not need to edit the upstart process (or is it init?)

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/573000/what-is-mounting-windows-7-file-system/573008?noredirect=1#comment790658_573008

Answer (score 0):

fstab is a file, found in /etc - it belongs to root so you must use sudo to edit it - it controls where all the components of the filesystem go.
mkdir is just a command to create a directory.

If you wanted your drive to appear as, say, ~/windows, you would want to create that directory;

`cd ~ ; mkdir windows`

You then want to find out how the system  sees /dev/sda3:
`sudo blkid /dev/sda3`

/dev/sda3: LABEL="Var" UUID="4b0b7c0f-c09e-47a4-a5a6-c9ac3c8184a9" TYPE="ntfs"

This is because if you ever add another drive, the lettering may alter but the UUID won't. You can also see what format it has: ntfs most likely.

Then, you're ready to make the change -

`sudo nano /etc/fstab` or whatever editor you like.. and add the line

UUID=b0b7c0f-c09e-47a4-a5a6-c9ac3c8184a9 /home/you/windows ntfs defaults,user   0   2

to /etc/fstab - note that the UUID quotes are not used in the fstab. I have used ntfs in the example - use whatever format it gave from blkid! The final 2 numbers are 0 - pretty much always, see `man fstab` if you really want to know, & 2 - mount this after all the pass 0 & pass 1 drives so as not to delay boot.

Try `sudo mount -a` to check it actually works.

This doesn't take account of what seems a long delay in mounting at present - it may be a good idea to run a drive check in Windows?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/573000/what-is-mounting-windows-7-file-system/573008?noredirect=1#comment790658_573008

Comment: hey !! thanks man, now it worked, at first i had a simple issue, did a dumb copy/paste without changing the UUID :S

thanksman, really appreciate the help :) (i would have uped the answer... im 4 rep point short :'( sorry )